# How to retrieve value from LinkedHashMap using variables?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, linkedhashmap

I would like to create variable which allows me to access to vary YAML structures.

envFile is the YAML file contains data like:

```
ENVNAME:
  MYSYS:
    MYSUBSYS:
      MYDETAIL:
        version: 1.0.0
        path: C:\wwwroot\sys
  MYSYS2:
    MYSUBSYS2:
      version: 1.0.1
      path: C:\wwwroot\sys2
```

Important is that MYSYS2 doesn't have MYDETAIL level

In Jenkins pipeline I'm using:

```
envs = readYaml file: envFile
```

Then I can get version value using:

```
verNum = envs."${environment}"."${sysName}"."${subSysName}"."${detailName}".version
```

But when I want get version for MYSYS2 then I should use (no detailName):

```
verNum = envs."${environment}"."${sysName}"."${subSysName}".version
```

So I need variable depends on sysName..

I would like to use syntax like:

```
if (sysName == 'MYSYS'){
  mySuperVariable = "${environment}"."${sysName}"."${subSysName}"."${detailName}"
}
else if (sysName == 'MYSYS2'){
  mySuperVariable = "${environment}"."${sysName}"."${subSysName}"
}

(...)

sysVer = envs."${mySuperVariable}".version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you could access maps via `map[key][sub-key]`. So in your case it would be:

```
if (sysName == 'MYSYS'){
  mySuperVariable = envs[environment][sysName][subSysName][detailName]
}
else if (sysName == 'MYSYS2'){
  mySuperVariable = envs[environment][sysName][subSysName]
}

(...)

sysVer = mySuperVariable['version']
```

Comment: It works, but only if I use sysVer = mySuperVariable.version in last line. Anybody can explain why?

Comment: `version` is not a variable in your case I guess. So if it would be `mySuperVariable["version"]` or `mySuperVariable.version`. The others are working, because they are variables which contain a string. I am adjusting the answer accordingly now